# mysql insert multi row query result into table

Tags: mysql

I came across a scenario where I need to "upgrade" a table with data I obtain from another query. I am adding missing values so I will need to insert, but I cant seem to get it right.

The destination table is the following

```
CREATE TABLE `documentcounters` (
  `UID` int,
  `DataChar`,
  `SeqNum` ,
  `LastSignature`,
  `DocumentType`,
  `SalesTerminal`,
  `Active`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and I am trying to do something like

```
INSERT INTO documentcounters
SELECT Q1.in_headers, -1,NULL, 17,0,0 FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DocumentSeries) as in_headers  FROM transactionsheaders )AS Q1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DataChar) as in_counters FROM documentcounters)AS Q2
ON Q1.in_headers=Q2.in_counters WHERE Q2.in_counters IS NULL;
```

I left UID out because I want the insert statement to create it, but I get a "Column count doesn't match" which makes sense (darn!)

Doing something like

```
INSERT INTO `documentcounters`
(`DataChar`,`SeqNum`,`LastSignature`,`DocumentType`,`SalesTerminal`,`Active`)
VALUES
(
(SELECT Q1.in_headers FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DocumentSeries) as in_headers  FROM transactionsheaders )AS Q1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DataChar) as in_counters FROM documentcounters)AS Q2
ON Q1.in_headers=Q2.in_counters WHERE Q2.in_counters IS NULL),-1,NULL,17,0,0
);
```

yields a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Cheers

Comment: if you run the sub queries separate do they only return 1 record?

Comment: @Robert. No, I can have more than one record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `documentcounters`
(`DataChar`,`SeqNum`,`LastSignature`,`DocumentType`,`SalesTerminal`,`Active`)
SELECT Q1.in_headers, -1,NULL, 17,0,0 FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DocumentSeries) as in_headers  FROM transactionsheaders )AS Q1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DataChar) as in_counters FROM documentcounters)AS Q2
ON Q1.in_headers=Q2.in_counters WHERE Q2.in_counters IS NULL;
```

This will work if `UID` is defined as `auto_increment`.

Comment: just remove Values and that's it?!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the INSERT to create the `UID` values, then `UID` must be defined as an [auto-incrementing column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

```
CREATE TABLE `documentcounters` (
  `UID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
```