# Displaying multiple query results in a single jTable returning unusual results and missing info

Tags: java, mysql, swing

What I want to do is execute multiple two queries and the show the results in a jTable. I tried using the UNION but weird results came out in the table like this:

```
[B@58f67fc  3
[B@9f3d43e  1
[B@66f3378c 3
[B@69c3fd21 4
[B@421fb7c6 3
```

instead of actual usernames

I already looked at:  [mysql insert multi row query result into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897756/mysql-insert-multi-row-query-result-intotable)?

This is what I used:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection CC = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pulsedb", "root", "carrizo");
        String getID  = "SELECT stuff_id,med_specialty FROM mstuffinfo UNION ALL SELECT username,user_level FROM mstufflogin";
        PreparedStatement PS = CC.prepareStatement(getID);

        ResultSet RS = PS.executeQuery();

        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(RS));
    }
    catch(SQLException SQ)
    {
        SQ.printStackTrace();
        SQ.getErrorCode();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PulseSTUFFLIST.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

[image: I got this]

Comment: Before converting to tablemodel do this.. `RS.next();` then `System.out.println(RS.getString("stuff_id"));` Then see whether you are getting correct `stuff_id` or not.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: stuff_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key                     //auto-increment starts from 1000

Comment: @AJ That works well...It prints correct usernames

Comment: @tpmabb Code of `resultSetToTableModel` is given at [technojeeves](http://technojeeves.com/index.php/9-freebies/22-resultset-to-tablemodel).